Issues with Audio and Video Quality Using chrome.tabCapture in Chrome Extension
I'm developing a Chrome extension to record tab content along with microphone audio. I'm facing two primary issues:
1.The recorded video does not include the microphone audio. 
2.The video quality of the recording is not satisfactory.
Flow of the Extension: 
popup.js: This is the main UI for the extension, where the user initiates recording.
background.js: Handles background tasks, manages state, and communicates between popup.js and content.js. 
content.js: Injected into the tab to handle media capture and recording.
Current Implementation 
popup.js
// User clicks to start recording
const handleStart = () => {
  try {
    chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({ consumerTabId: tabId }, (streamId) => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ command: 'tab-media-stream', tabId: tabId, streamId: streamId, userEmail });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error starting recording: ", error);
  }
};

// Request permissions for microphone and webcam
<div onClick={() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "askWebcam" })} className='flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 px-2 py-3 my-2 rounded-md bg-[#474747]'>
  <Webcam size={20} />
  <h1 className='text-base'>Default - web-cam</h1>
</div>
<div onClick={() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "askAudio" })} className='flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 px-2 py-3 my-2 rounded-md bg-[#474747]'>
  <Mic size={20} />
  <h1 className='text-base'>Default - Laptop's mic</h1>
</div>

// On mount, query for the active tab ID
useEffect(() => {
  if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ command: 'query-active-tab' }, (response) => {
      if (response) {
        setTabId(response.id);
      } else {
        console.error('No response from query-active-tab');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('chrome.runtime is not available');
  }
  checkUser();
}, []);


background.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.command === "query-active-tab") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, (tabs) => {
      if (tabs.length > 0) {
        sendResponse({ id: tabs[0].id });
      }
    });
    return true;
  }

  if (message.command === "tab-media-stream") {
    const streamId = message.streamId;
    userEmail = message.userEmail;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.tabId, {
      command: "tab-media-stream",
      streamId: message.streamId,
    });
  }

  if (message.action === "askAudio") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
        files: ["content.js"],
      }, () => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "askAudio" });
      });
    });
  }

  if (message.action === "askWebcam") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
        files: ["content.js"],
      }, () => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "askWebcam" });
      });
    });
  }
});


content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "askAudio") {
    try {
      const userMediaOptions = {
        audio: {
          echoCancellation: true,
          noiseSuppression: true,
          sampleRate: 44100,
        },
        video: false,
      };
      audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(userMediaOptions);
      console.log("Microphone access granted.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error accessing microphone:", error);
    }
  }

  if (request.command === "tab-media-stream") {
    try {
      const streamId = request.streamId;
      const constraints = {
        audio: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
            chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
            echoCancellation: true,
            noiseSuppression: true,
            sampleRate: 44100,
          },
        },
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
            chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
            maxWidth: window.innerWidth,
            maxHeight: window.innerHeight,
            minWidth: window.innerWidth,
            minHeight: window.innerHeight,
            minFrameRate: 30,
            maxFrameRate: 60,
          },
        },
      };
      const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
      recordingStartTime = Date.now();

      // Create AudioContext and route audio
      const audioContext = new AudioContext();
      const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
      const audioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
      audioSource.connect(audioDestination);
      const audioStream2 = audioDestination.stream;
//Creating this captures the current audio of the system but again it is not there in the recorded video

      const combinedTracks = [...media.getTracks()];
      if (audioStream) {
        combinedTracks.push(...audioStream.getTracks());
      }
      if (audioStream2) {
        combinedTracks.push(...audioStream2.getTracks());
      }
      if (webcamStream) {
        combinedTracks.push(...webcamStream.getTracks());
      }
      mixedStream = new MediaStream(combinedTracks);
      handleMediaStream(mixedStream, audioStream, webcamStream);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error capturing tab media: ", error);
    }
  }
});


Issues: 
Audio Recording Issue:Despite including the microphone audio stream, the recorded video does not contain any audio. I am separately capturing the microphone audio, but it's not being integrated into the video stream.

Video Quality Issue:
The quality of the recorded video is not satisfactory. I'm looking for ways to improve the video quality to at least 720p HD.


Additional Information: 
The getDisplayMedia method works well and includes the microphone audio in the video, but it captures the entire screen. I need to capture only the tab content. 
I have already tried adjusting the video constraints for higher resolution and frame rate, but the quality is still not as expected. 
Any help or insights on these issues would be greatly appreciated!
